# What is 'extra' in pypi dependency?

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-packaging

In `requires_dist` section of a package's json response from pypi, it is given:

```
requires_dist : [
    "bcrypt; extra == 'bcrypt'",
    "argon2-cffi (>=16.1.0); extra == 'argon2'"
]
```

can anyone make it clear the second statement of each dependency, `extra == 'bcrypt'` and `extra == 'argon2'`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Extras are dependencies you can install *in addition* to the regular dependencies, if you ask for them explicitly. See them as optional features.

You can install these with the name after the `==`, with the name of the package. For example, if you install `somepackage` and want to add the `bcrypt` optional feature, use:

```
pip install somepackage[bcrypt]
```

or

```
pip install somepackage[argon2]
```

or, to include both optional extras, separate the names with commas:

```
pip install somepackage[bcrypt,argon2]
```

although using `somepackage[...]` multiple times also works as `pip` is smart enough to know that the main package is already installed.

`pip` (or whatever other package install tool) maps names listed in `<packagename>[<extras_name>(,...)]` to those entries in the `requires_dict` that use the `<dependency_spec>; extra == '<extras_name>'` format, adding on the `dependency_spec`s to the list of things to install.

See [*Installing Setuptools "Extras"*](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-setuptools-extras) in the *Installing Packages* section of the [*Python Packaging User Guide*](https://packaging.python.org/).

It is up to the installed package itself to detect if all the dependencies for optional extra features are installed. A common pattern is to use `try...except ImportError:` guards to test for such extra dependencies being available.

Comment: Can you give an example with this dependency? `"argon2-cffi (>=16.1.0); extra == 'argon2'"`  
I have came across something like `somepackage[bcrypt]` when installing `celery` but cant relate to the type dependency in the question.

Comment: @Marty: `somepackage[argon2]` would install the package with that optional extra.

Comment: what is somepackage anyway when coming to `"argon2-cffi (>=16.1.0); extra == 'argon2'"`? is it `argon2-cffi[argon2]>=16.1.0`?

Comment: @Marty: no, it's the name of the package you found this specification in.

Comment: so if the package is django, how does it relate? `Django[argon2]`? so this `argon2-cffi (>=16.1.0)` prefered over `Django[argon2]` in the statement or vice versa?

Comment: @Marty: if you use `pip install Django[argon2]` then `pip` adds `argon2-cffi >=16.1.0` to the dependencies to install. Use `Django[argon2]`, always, because that way you make the Django2 package responsible for specifying the right packages and versions.

Comment: so this is something to say 'install `argon2`' version that `Django` depends on?

Comment: @Marty: yes, it means Django will use argon2-cffi if you installed that package, and then Django can make use of that, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/#using-argon2-with-django

Comment: using `zsh` I had to put the package name into single quotes in order for it to work:  `pip install 'somepackage[bcrypt]'`