# How to pin pipenv requirements with brackets?

Tags: python, django, pipenv, argon2-ffi

I just did:

```
pipenv install django[argon2]
```

And this changed my `Pipfile`:

```
-django = "==2.1.5"
+django = {extras = ["argon2"],version = "*"}
```

I want to pin the requirements. First I will pin `django` to `2.1.5`:

```
django = {extras = ["argon2"],version = "==2.1.5"}
```

What about `argon2`? Is that a separate package? There is no such package when I do `pip freeze`:

```
$ pip freeze  | grep -i argon2
argon2-cffi==19.1.0
```

What is that? How do I fully pin `django[argon2]`?

Answer (score 9):

In my `Pipfile`, I found this possible by double-quoting the package and the version

```
[packages]
"django[argon2]" = "==2.1.5"
```

Answer (score 6):

From the [Requirement Specifier](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers) docs for pip, you can combine these forms:

> ```
> SomeProject == 1.3  
> SomeProject >=1.2,<2.0  
> SomeProject[foo, bar]
> ```

This means you can do this command:

```
pipenv install "django[argon2]==2.1.5"
```

Which generates this Pipfile entry:

```
django = {version = "==2.1.5", extras = ["argon2"]}
```

That command installs Django and:

1. Pins Django at version 2.1.5 (or whatever is specified as `==VERSION`)
2. Includes [Django's optional support for Argon2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/#using-argon2-with-django)

There is no `argon2` package. The `[argon2]` means it is an [optional dependency or an optional feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474931/what-is-extra-in-pypi-dependency) of Django. What gets installed is the `argon2-cffi` and `cffi` packages, which are the optional dependencies Django needs to use Argon2. You can see this in the Pipfile.lock:

```
"argon2-cffi": {
    "hashes": [
        ...
    ],
    "version": "==20.1.0"
},
"cffi": {
    "hashes": [
        ...
    ],
    "version": "==1.14.6"
},
"django": {
    "extras": [
        "argon2"
    ],
    "hashes": [
        ...
    ],
    "index": "pypi",
    "version": "==2.1.5"
},
```

This is also mentioned in [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/#using-argon2-with-django):

> To use Argon2 as your default storage algorithm, do the following:
>
> 1. This can be done by running **`python -m pip install django[argon2]`**, which is equivalent to **`python -m pip install argon2-cffi`** (along with any version requirement from Django’s **`setup.cfg`**)

The difference of doing `pipenv install django[argon2]` compared to installing `django` and `argon2-cffi` separately (as with [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54576454/2745495)) is that, during installation, you let Django's setuptools decide which version of `argon2-cffi` to use. This is better because the Django maintainers probably wrote and tested the code for Argon2 support *using a compatible version* of `argon2-cffi`.

This can be seen in [Django's setup.cfg](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.2.6/setup.cfg#L53) file (for Django 3.2.6 at the time of this writing):

```
[options.extras_require]
argon2 = argon2-cffi >= 19.1.0
```

which indicates that when using optional `[argon2]` feature it needs to install that range of version of `argon2-cffi`. As [James O' Brien commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576171/how-to-pin-pipenv-requirements-with-brackets#comment109707918_54576454): "*A specific version of django would require specific versions of the extras.*"

Answer (score 0):

If you want full control you can:

> pipenv install "django==2.1.5" "argon2-cffi==19.1"

Is it what you need?

Comment: Well, I am not even sure what I am doing with `pip install django[argon2]`, or how that compares to your command. Am I installing two packages? Am I installing a single package (django), with a different flavor? Can I then pin django and argon2 separately? Questions, questions, ...

Comment: You are installing with setup [extras](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#options) (see option 6) described in [setuptools documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies). I never quite understood motivation behind extras and it looks as they are not fully supported by pipenv command line.

Comment: It probably would not be advisable to pin the extras. A specific version of django would require specific versions of the extras. If you want to see what gets installed, search for `argon2` in the `Pipfile.lock`