# Creating a Package that Installs in an Existing Package

Tags: python, package

I would like to create a very modular package, where users can install pieces if need be.  I was wondering if there is a way to create multiple small packages and a master package.  A user would first install the master package then install the components as needed.

I've tried researching this way, but I think I have the terminology wrong, I am hoping that someone can point me to some documentation or example project doing this.

Comment: Go with "extras": https://stackoverflow.com/a/52475030/7976758; see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+extras

Comment: thank you for the search and terminology