# Python way to declare test dependencies

Tags: python, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

According to the Zen of Python... Python's test dependency management is not preferable.

There are dozens upon dozen of ways to manage test dependencies. For instance: dev-dependencies.txt, setup.py extras_require, tests_require, setup.cfg, some sort of tox incantation (tox supports anything you can dream up), I think maybe a tools section of pyproject.toml?

Is there a good write up anywhere on the current best practice? This is a wild one to navigate, there are so many possibilities, I can't seem to find consensus anywhere.

If there isn't a general consensus on how to do this is there a best way that integrates well with PyCharm? Most of my build experience is with Java through Gradle/Maven which does have a fairly opinionated way of handling dependencies, I'm looking for something similar (something strongly opinionated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is somewhat opinion-based, but I think the current best practice would be to put your test dependencies into [an extra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474931/what-is-extra-in-pypi-dependency) in `pyproject.toml` (assuming, of course, that you're using `pyproject.toml` like a good modern project should; if you're not, [I recommend Hatch](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/intro/#existing-project)).

```
[project.optional-dependencies]
test = [
    "pytest",
    "pytest-cov",
]
```

This way you can install these in your local work environment with `pip install -e .[test]` (i.e. "install this package as editable, with the `test` extra) and in `tox.ini`, if you want, with

```
[testenv]
extras = test
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the answer, now I've got to go learn what Hatch is. What is the relationship between pyproject.toml and Hatch?

Comment: Okay, got it. Hatch uses pyproject.toml in the way pyproject.toml is intended to be used to manage the full build. I think the relationship between hatch, hatchling, PEP 517, and PEP 518 is what I am looking for with my question.

Comment: Yep, that's about it. Hatchling is Hatch's PEP517 build backend, and Hatch builds on it for additional management features.